# How to allow registry (write) access fo my .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, uac

I've got error message :

**Requested registry access is denied**

when trying to **write** into registery keys with turned on **UAC** :

```
RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "")
tawkey.OpenSubKey(x, true).SetValue(X, V, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

Must I run **"subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\PathToMyKeys... /grant=user=f"** during My software installation ? Or there is some other way to have access to my registry keys ?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to do this on a remote machine?

Comment: not - on my own machine.

Comment: If its alocal machine, why use OpenRemoteBaseKey??

Comment: just... do you recommend to use Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey ? sadly it shows same error.

Comment: @nCdy  `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey` is definitely better but the problem you have is that standard users do not have write access to `HKLM`. You won't get around that by using different registry access APIs. They will all fail in the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to write to keys under `HKLM`, you need an elevated process. This is achieved by setting `requestedExecutionLevel` to `requireAdministrator` in the application's manifest.

Making this change means that your application will present a UAC elevation dialog every time it runs. This will no doubt be irritating and so here are some options of avoiding that irritation:

1. Write to somewhere other than `HLKM` where standard users have write access.
2. Perform the writes to `HLKM` in your install program.
3. Arrange that you elevate on demand if writing to `HLKM` is only needed for occasionally used functionality in your program.

Option 3 needs a little elaboration. You can't elevate a process once it has started. You can only elevate at process start time. So in order to implement option 3, you need that functionality to exist in a separate process or out of process COM server. If you go down this route remember to include the shield icon on any UI element that results in a UAC dialog.

Comment: got strange message : ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'

Comment: Can you explain where ClickOnce comes into this. I didn't see that in your question. FWIW I understand that ClickOnce and UAC elevation are not meant to go together: http://www.geektieguy.com/2007/08/25/getting-vista-uac-elevation-to-work-for-web-deployed-clickonce-applications/